# Can android OS push information about network connecting status to application?

Tags: android, networking

I need some advices about the Android OS and application.

I wonder if the Android OS is able to push network connecting status to applications.
(I found applications can get a network connecting status from android OS. But I can't find reverse cases.)

However, I am thinking android OS may push network connecting status to applications.

---

when application is installed on android os, is it possible to register something for monitoring phone's network status on android os.

Because I want my application can receive phone's network status from android os.(not by asking directly to android os.)

It means: 
when phone's network status changes, does android os automatically informs phone's network status to application?

I'm sorry my English writing is bad TT;

Have a nice weekend~

Korean: 
안드로이드 OS에서 직접 어플리케이션에 네트워크 상태 변화를 알리도록 할 수 있는 방법이 있을까요?

만약 저 방법이 안된다면,
안드로이드에 어플리케이션이 설치될 때 어플리케이션과 연결된 listener(혹은 유사한 무엇)를 안드로이드 OS에 설치할 수 있을까요? 
이 listener가 어플리케이션과는 상관 없이 안드로이드 OS의 네트워크 상태를 확인해 네트워크 상태가 변경되면 해당 정보를 어플리케이션에 보내주는 형태로 개발해보고 싶습니다.

좋은 정보나 조언 등 있으시면 부탁드리겠습니다.

즐거운 주말 되세요~

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking; your comments about not finding reverse cases seems contradictory.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676044/broadcast-intent-when-network-state-has-changend

Answer (score 6):

From [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) documentation:

> Class that answers queries about the
>   state of network connectivity. It also
>   notifies applications when network
>   connectivity changes.

Comment: Sadly there is no example in the connectivity manager on how to exactly do the listening

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for **phone network connection status** then register your PhoneStateListener by passing it to [android.telephony.TelephonyManager listen](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen%28android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int%29)

See [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.htm) for a list of listening options.
**Note: **this only applies to Cellular network connection status changes not wifi, etc.