# Broadcast Intent when network state has changend

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

Does Android broadcast an intent when the network state has changend, i.e. from GSM to Wifi? And if so what permission do I need and what is the intent action called?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update:** please use this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2677519/241869

Comment: I'm not familiar with the subject matter, but a talk at Defcon pointed out an error in this answer.  See slide 51 from the [presentation](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~emc/slides/SevenWaysToHangYourselfWithGoogleAndroid.pdf).  Could somebody update this accordingly?

Comment: I don't see how this answer relates to the question. The network connectivity could change from cellphone network to Bluetooth tethering and the code would never know it. **Please don't use this.** **AI's answer** regarding **ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION** points in the right direction.

Answer (score 10):

There isn't anything exactly like what you are describing but you can use `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` to monitor changes and use the extras that come with it to see if the connection has changed from GSM to Wifi and vice versa. For this you need the permission `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` and `android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` for checking wifi information.

Comment: I don't see why CONNECTIVITY_ACTION isn't what was asked for. Also, personally, I don't need android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE to receive the CONNECTIVITY_ACTION event. Apart from that... thank you for providing the right answer to the question!

Answer (score 1):

Android will broadcast `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` when the devices
gains or looses wifi connectivity.  You'll need the permission `android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` to receive the intent.  However, I'm not sure if
there's something similar for GSM -> WIFI.

Comment: In the question, WiFi was only mentioned as an example. The question refers to the network state in general, independently of the particular WiFi connectivity.