# How to listen to WifiMonitor events

Tags: android, android-wifi

My question is about detecting that my cellphone wifi connection is bound to a network and is operationnal.

I Can see such a line in the LogCat (tagged "WifiMonitor")

```
VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(93): Event [CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to c4:3d:c7:89:cf:c0 completed (auth) [id=8 id_str=]]
```

That did let me hope that event was catchable... But How ?

Thank your for attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at the ConnectivityManager: [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)

And

```
public boolean isWifiOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I read the doc, but I didn't find anything about an event that would be fired the moment isWifiOnline returns true.

Comment: Maybe I didn't seek it enough!

Comment: For that you need to create a BroadcastReceiver: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676044/broadcast-intent-when-network-state-has-changend

Comment: Oh I need to ask you for advice again, because, that code won't work for one reason : My application must switch on wifi and wait for network connection AND for the device connection to switch from GPRS for example. All in the same process. When this is done, I directly fire a http query, that won't work.

Comment: I have edited my previous comment: should solve your problem. Concerning what you just describe, your application will be notified when the network changes, and after that it is your responsibility to manage the different states (WiFi connected, switch to GPRS, etc.) and fire your http query.